# RNN model predicting only one class?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to use GloVe embeddings to train a rnn model based on [this article](https://github.com/kk7nc/Text_Classification#long-short-term-memory-lstm).
I have a labeled data: text(tweets) on one column, labels on another (hate, offensive or neither). 
However the model seems to predict only one class in the result.

This is the LSTM model:

```
model = Sequential()
hidden_layer = 3
gru_node = 32

# model embedding matrix here....

for i in range(0,hidden_layer):
    model.add(GRU(gru_node,return_sequences=True, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout))
model.add(GRU(gru_node, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(Dropout(dropout))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='softmax'))
model.add(Dense(nclasses, activation='softmax'))
start=time.time()
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

fitting the model:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 1)
X_train_Glove,X_test_Glove, word_index, embeddings_index = loadData_Tokenizer(X_train, X_test)

model_RNN = Build_Model_RNN_Text(word_index,embeddings_index, 20)    
model_RNN.fit(X_train_Glove,y_train,
                            validation_data=(X_test_Glove, y_test),
                            epochs=4,
                            batch_size=128,
                            verbose=2)
y_preds = model_RNN.predict_classes(X_test_Glove)
print(metrics.classification_report(y_test, y_preds))
```

Results:

1. classification report

[image: classifn report]

2. Confusion matrix

[image: confus_mat]

Am I missing something here?

**Update**:
this is what the distribution looks like
[image: distribn]

and the model summary, more or less

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How the distribution of your data looks like? The first suggestion is to stratify train/test split (here is the [link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) for the documentation).

The second question is how much data do you have in comparison with the complexity of the model? Maybe, your model is so complex, that just do overfitting. You can use the command [model.summary()](https://keras.io/models/about-keras-models/) to see the number of trainable parameters.