# CNN model overfitting on multi-class classification

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to use GloVe embeddings to train a cnn model based on [this article](https://github.com/kk7nc/Text_Classification#recurrent-convolutional-neural-networks-rcnn) (also a rnn, which has [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57748144/7876828)). The dataset is a labeled data: text (tweets) with labels (hate, offensive or neither).

The problem is that model performs well on train set but poorly on validation set.

here is the model:

```
kernel_size = 2
filters = 256
pool_size = 2
gru_node = 64
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(len(word_index) + 1,
                            EMBEDDING_DIM,
                            weights=[embedding_matrix],
                            input_length=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,
                            trainable=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv1D(filters, kernel_size, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=pool_size))
model.add(Conv1D(filters, kernel_size, activation='softmax'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=pool_size))
model.add(LSTM(gru_node, return_sequences=True, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(LSTM(gru_node, return_sequences=True, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(LSTM(gru_node, return_sequences=True, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(LSTM(gru_node, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(Dense(1024,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(nclasses))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

fitting the model:

```
X = df.tweet
y = df['classifi']    # classes 0,1,2

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, shuffle=False)
X_train_Glove,X_test_Glove, word_index,embeddings_index = loadData_Tokenizer(X_train,X_test)

model_RCNN = Build_Model_RCNN_Text(word_index,embeddings_index, 20)

model_RCNN.fit(X_train_Glove, y_train,validation_data=(X_test_Glove, y_test),
                              epochs=15,batch_size=128,verbose=2)

predicted = model_RCNN.predict(X_test_Glove)

predicted = np.argmax(predicted, axis=1)
print(metrics.classification_report(y_test, predicted))
```

this is what the distribution looks like (0:hate, 1:offensive, 2:neither)

[image: distribn]

model summary

[image: model]

Results:

1. classification report
   [image]

is this the correct approach or am I missing something here

Comment: you got 1M parameter in first layer. I don't know if this done on purpose but it's seem very big

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking there are two sides that you can tackle overfitting:

1. Improving the data

   - More unique data
   - oversampling (to balance data)
2. Limiting the network structure

   - Dropout (You've implemented this)
   - Less parameters (You might want to benchmark against a much smaller network)
   - regularization (ex. L1 and L2)

I'd suggest trying with significantly fewer parameters (because this is quick) and oversampling (because your data seems lopsided).

Also, You can also try hyperparameter fitting. Making a large number of networks with different parameters than picking the best one.

Note: if you do hyper parameter fitting make sure to have an extra validation set because you can easily overfit your test set this way.

Side note: Sometimes when troubleshooting NN it is helpful to set the optimizer to a basic stochastic gradient descent. It slows the training down a bunch but makes the progression much clearer.

Good luck!